# python, string, input and integer, stuck on part C of the question

Tags: python

```
#Exercise 5
#a Ask the user for a birth year using the prompt: birthyear? (include a space after the ?)
#b Convert the user input to an integer
#c Subtract the user entered birthyear from 2019
#d Convert the result of the previous line and the user entry to strings using the str() function
#e Display the following using the + concatenator in a print statement (note the punctuation and spacing):
#f It has been [converted result of line 5c]! years since your birthyear in [converted user entry]!
#g Hence, if user entered 2010, display:
#h It has been 9! years since your birthyear in 2010
#i Next, display the words: You were born in the year:
#j Display the converted user entered birthyear vertically, one digit at a time.
#k For example, for 2010 display (ignore the # signs):
#2
#0
#1
#0  
birthyear=int(input('birthyear? '))
age=2019-birthyear
```

The output 
    File "main.py", line 95
    age=2019-birthyear
          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I am stuck at part C where I need to subtract the user enter birthday from 2019. When I did is age=2019-birthyear it said syntax error. How do I name the variable name?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
What little code you've posted appears to run just fine.

Comment: Avoid external links but include relevant parts of assignments and your code as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be in the shown part of the code. Additionally: Use copy & paste to show code and error messages here to avoid typos.

Comment: hint : check type(2019) and type(birthyear)

Comment: Please update your question with the *exact* code you have right now and the *exact* and *complete* error message it generates. From all the edits and answers to previous typos it is hard to tell what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote birthyear with a capital Y. Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: I have changed that already it's just said the age is not identified

Comment: I tries this code and it works for me: birthyear = int(input('birthyear? '))
age = 2019 - birthyear
print(age)

Comment: This what I will get. How do I fix this?                                                                                    birthyear? Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 94, in <module>
birthyear = int(input('birthyear? ')) 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'b'

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a second closing parenthesis after the `birthyear=` assignment. You have `int(input(...)` with two left parens and one right parens.

Edit: You changed the original problem text. The only remaining issue I see is that your `birthyear=` and `age=` lines start with a blank space. When I removed the blank space, it works exactly as hoped.

Edit 2: From your comment:

```
>>> b=int(input('birthyear? '))
birthyear? 23
>>> b
23
```

So that works correctly. If your command line input is invalid, though:

```
>>> b=int(input('birthyear? '))
birthyear? boo!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'boo!'
```

That blows up with an error similar to what you saw.

Comment: When I add a parenthesis on the left I will get this .                                              birthyear? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 94, in <module>
    b=int(input('birthyear? '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'b'